# Getting web API path from swagger

Tags: c#, api, web-services, swagger

I have swagger URL http://somehost/swagger/index.html
end methods there as shown on image:
[image]

As someone said to me http://somehost/api/Referral/GetReferralByNumber is API address which I can refer it by HTTP request.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                string result = client.DownloadString("http://somehost/api/Referral/GetReferralByNumber");
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(ex);

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

this is code for testing API, but

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
> Not Found exception

is thrown. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Client.DownloadString() makes an GET request. Your action supports POST. Try to use HttpClient, it should be better for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a Get Request and for Get request there is no such endpoint.

You should try adding the HTTP option Post to the server.

**Code**:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/referral/GetReferralByNumber", data);
```

Where `data` is the data which should be posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an http client and use POST like this:

```
var method = HttpMethod.Post;
var endPoint = "http://somehost/api/Referral/GetReferralByNumber";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, endPoint);
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```